# Use custom column in for loop Angular template

Tags: angular

I wrote the following code:

**table.component.html**

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">

<table mat-table [dataSource]="tableDataSrc" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let col of tableCols">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="{{ col }}">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
            {{ col | titlecase }}
            </th>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!(col == 'view')" >
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let profile">{{ profile[col] }}</td>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="col == 'view'" >
                <td matc-cell>Custom Value</td>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableCols"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableCols"></tr>
</table>

<mat-paginator (page)="pageChange.emit($event)"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[15]" 
               showFirstLastButtons
               [length]="length">
</mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**teams.component.html**

```
<app-table *ngIf="!loading" (pageChange)="handlePageChange($event)" [tableData]="teams" [tableColumns]="tableCols" [length]="length"></app-table>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.scss']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  tableDataSrc: any;

  @Input('tableColumns') tableCols: string[];
  @Input() tableData: {}[] = [];
  @Input() length : number; 

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  @Output() pageChange = new EventEmitter<PageEvent>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(changes.tableData.currentValue) {
        this.tableDataSrc = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableData);
        this.tableDataSrc.sort = this.sort;
    }
}

}
```

**teams.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teams',
  templateUrl: './teams.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./teams.component.scss']
})
export class TeamsComponent implements OnInit {
  public teams : Array<Team>; 
  public length : any; 
  public loading : boolean = true; 

  tableCols = ['sofascore_id', 'name', 'view'];

  constructor(private teamService : TeamService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTeams(); 
  }

  fetchTeams(pageNumber = 1){
    this.teamService.getTeams(pageNumber).subscribe(
      data => {

        this.teams = data.results
        this.length = data.count
        this.loading = false; 
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.error)
      }
    )
  }

  handlePageChange(event: PageEvent) {
    // this.loading = true; 
    this.fetchTeams(event.pageIndex + 1)
  }

}
```

When I run this code, the page is rendered properly, the table is loaded and the column headers are filled in in it, but the content is not loaded into the table. Removing the ng containers wrapping around the elements containing the td and removing the last td the data is loaded properly into the table but the 'view' column stays empty

I want to fill in custom data in the table row when the column name is 'view', using the code I wrote I get the following error: `ERROR TypeError: "column.cell is undefined"`

Answer (score 1):

When I was getting this error is was because the children of my `<ng-container matColumnDef="colName">`

was not

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Col name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.data}}% </td>
```

Specifically in my case, someone had commented out the `<td mat-cell` line.  So the error saying the column couldn't find the cell actually made sense.

Comment: The error can also occur when the `*matCellDef` is missing on the td element